# UIcollection view does not scroll?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I have added a `UICollectionView` in my app. I have given its constraints like leading, trailing, top & some fixed height of the collection view. It is showing all items. But I am not able to scroll it. Please tell what is the issue?

```
   func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print("count is \(arr_collection.count)")
        return arr_collection.count
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let identifier="col_cell"
        let cell:CollectionCell
        cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath ) as! CollectionCell
        cell.img_cell.image=UIImage(named: arr_collection[indexPath.row])
        print("arr collection is \(arr_collection[indexPath.row])")
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I have experienced that I can't scroll if my content in the UiCollectionview is not exceeding the boundaries of the screen. Is that the case?
It is possible to scroll even though the content is less than the view, but I don't know how

Comment: dont give fix height.top bottom leading trailing constraint may solve your issue.

Comment: so what yor are trying to say is that all items in UiCollectionView are visibe and UiCollectionView is not scrolling ? If yes then I believe that this should be happening because there is nothing to scroll for.

Comment: did you allow userInteractionunabled??

Answer (score 4):

CollectionViews in Interface builder by default have "Bounces" property enabled, but you must specify what direction it bounces in. If you don't, and the content of the Collection View does not exceed the boundaries of the collection view, you won't be able to scroll.
[image]